# Question about proof for Euclid's lemma using greatest common divisor

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization, gcd-and-lcm

I have been asked to prove the following:

Let *p* be prime and *m,n* $\in$ **N**. If *p*|*mn* then *p*|*m* or *p*|*n*.

My book offers up the following proof:

1. Assume *p* divides *mn* but not *m*. We need to show that *p*|*n*. Since *p* is prime and does not divide *m*,  gcd = (*p,m*) = 1.
2. By Proposition 6.30: gcd (*mn,pn*) = *n* gcd (*m,p*) = *n*.
3. Then, by Proposition 6.29 (iii), since *p* divides both *mn* and *pn*, *p* also divides *n*. We conclude our proof.

I am having trouble with step 2 of this proof. Specifically, why are we multiplying by n?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The idea is to show that $p\mid n$, so the "trick" is to form two numbers that have a factor $n$ in order to use the property $\gcd(ac,bc)=c\gcd(a,b)$.

Comment: So are we basically multiplying the gcd by n in order to get gcd(mn,pn)?

Comment: Yes. That's the idea behind step 2.

Comment: Okay. How about step 3? After step 2, I am left with gcd(mn,pn)=n. How do I go from here to step 3?